# How can I avoid duplicating business logic in my Redux reducers?

Tags: redux

Lets say I have an application that displays issues for a given project. A user can open an issue, meaning they can see it on the screen, or close the issue, meaning it disappears. When I close the project, I want to also hide the issue visible to the user.

How can I avoid duplicating the business logic for mutating the state within the reducer? I can think of three options, and am wondering which is best, or what alternatives are available.

*Idea one:* Just repeat the code. I copy the `CLOSE_PROJECT` code into any method that needs it, like `CLOSE_ISSUE`.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_PROJECT:
      state.project = action.payload.project
    case CLOSE_PROJECT:
      state.project = null
      state.issue = null
    case CLOSE_ISSUE:
      state.issue = null
  }
}
```

*Idea two:* Move re-used code into helper functions. Pass the state into the helper function, get back the new state. (Note: I am using immer.js, but just picture this as psuedo code that doesn't actually mutate the state)

```
const closeProject = (state, action) => {
  state.project = null
  state
}

const closeIssue = (state, action) => {
  state.project = null
  state
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_PROJECT:
      state.project = action.payload.project
    case CLOSE_PROJECT:
      state = closeProject(state)
      state = closeIssue(state)
    case CLOSE_ISSUE:
      state.issue = null
  }
}
```

*Idea three:* Handle the logic outside of the reducer. Have helper functions that co-ordinate multiple dispatch calls.

```
const closeProject = (dispatch) {
  dispatch(closeProjectAction())
  dispatch(closeIssueAction())
}


const ReactThing = (dispatch) => {
  const handleCloseProjectClick = () => {
    closeProject(dispatcher)
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={ e => handleCloseProjectClick() }>Close</div>
  )
}
```

I think idea three is the best. But it feels strange to have all these business logic functions just kind of floating around outside of Redux. Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three options are entirely valid.  To some extent, it's a question of how you want to model your logic, and how you want to abstract common functionality.

There's a couple sections of the Redux docs that mostly address your questions:

- [Redux FAQ: Where should my "business logic" live?](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go)
- [Structuring Reducers: Reusing Reducer Logic](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic)

I also discussed several aspects related to this in my post [The Tao of Redux, Part 2: Practice and Philosophy](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/).

Also, as a side note: I strongly recommend using our [Redux Starter Kit package](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/), which uses Immer internally for simplified reducer setup.

Comment: I am using Redux starter. And thank you for the links -- funny to see a G.K. Chesterton reference there... But given that I'll read these, though not necessarily understand them for some time, would you make a recommendation? As always, "it depends", but with 30ish actions (growing to maybe 50) and a bunch of async calls, it'd be great to get a direction that to aim at. The understanding can come a bit later.

Comment: I would recommend trying to treat the actions more as "events", and have multiple portions of reducer logic respond to the same action.  So, notionally, probably closest to your example #1.  If the process of applying the update is complex, then feel free to extract that to a helper function as per example #2.  Example #3 isn't _wrong_, but there's not as much of a reason to dispatch multiple actions.  (Heh - it's been a while since I wrote the post and docs pages - which Chesterton ref is in there?)